# rally query with two conditions

Tags: ruby, rally

I want to query with two conditions in rally using ruby, and the query string is like:

```
(Name = \"#{iteration_name}\")" and "(Project.Name = \"#{project_name}\")
```

But no matter what operator was there between these two conditions, rally will ignore the left part of that. Does anyone know how to get the right query expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `(Name = \"#{iteration_name}\")` I assume that you query for iteration object.

Please use an extra set of parenthesis:

```
query.query_string = "((Name = \"#{iteration_name}\")AND(Project.Name = \"#{project_name}\"))"
```

Here is a code fragment:

```
iteration_name = "i10"
project_name = "Team Group 1"

rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :iteration   
query.fetch = "Name,Project"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111.js" }
query.project_scope_up = false
query.project_scope_down = false
query.order = "Name Asc"
query.query_string = "((Name = \"#{iteration_name}\")AND(Project.Name = \"#{project_name}\"))"

results = rally.find(query)
puts "iteration name: #{results.first.Name} project name:  #{results.first.Project.Name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

nickm already provided a good answer with examples.

In addition, please note that extra set of parenthesis only works for combining two terms with one AND.

((A)AND(B)AND(C)) won't work

So for using three or more, you'll have to add more:

```
(((A)AND(B))AND(C))
(((A)AND(B))AND((C)AND(D)))
```

and so on, only coming two terms with AND in one set of parenthesis.